# Break for loop inside closure

Tags: javascript

```
for (var e = 0; e < markers.length; e += 1) {
    (function (e, markers, latLngBounds) {
        if (latLngBounds.contains(markers[e])) {
            updatePrompt("Marker is contained");
            // Break for loop
        }
    })();
}
```

In the example above, after the `updatePrompt` method is invoked how can I break out of the loop containing the closure?

Comment: Your anonymous function is being called with no arguments...is that what you want?

Comment: you could just use the keyword 'break;'

Answer (score 3):

```
var broken = false;

for (var e = 0; e < markers.length; e += 1) {
    if (broken) {
        break;
    } else {
        (function (e, markers, latLngBounds) {
            if (latLngBounds.contains(markers[e])) {
                updatePrompt("Marker is contained");
                broken = true;
            }
        })();
    }
}
```

A little verbose, but you get the point.

This could also be done with `Array.some` in modern browsers

```
markers.some(function(marker) {
    if (latLngBounds.contains(marker)) {
        updatePrompt("Marker is contained");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what the IIFE is for, you're not passing anything in, but I guess it's just an example ?

Comment: Why not add `!broken` to the condition in the `for` statement?

Comment: @torazaburo - I was trying to make a point, and it seemed the most sense to write it that way I suppose !

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i get you correct, but if you want to break the loop set 
 e= markers.length;

The loop will not continue after this statement

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
for (var e = 0; e < markers.length; e += 1) {
    if ((function (e, markers, latLngBounds) {
        if (latLngBounds.contains(markers[e])) {
            updatePrompt("Marker is contained");
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    })())
        break;
}
```